# Kotlin Any with lambdas

Tags: lambda, kotlin

While the code provided with the question is rather trivial, the question focusses on the more general aspect of type safety:

Let's have a lambda function like this:

```
{it: (Any) -> Any -> it(it)}
```

It takes another lambda and executes it with itself as a parameter. So let's do the obvious and call it with itself as parameter:

```
{it: (Any) -> Any -> it(it)}.apply { this.invoke(this) }
```

But that does not work as well, as I thought: I get the following error at compile time:

**Type mismatch: inferred type is ((Any) -> Any) -> Any but (Any) -> Any was expected**

Ok. So let's try this one:

```
val lambda: (Any) -> Any = { Unit }
```

The actual value of this property doesn't matter, I am not interested in the result, just in the compiler behaviour. So here is another property:

```
 val kappa: (Any) -> Any = lambda
```

Ok, now this actually compiles. But isn't that the same thing as before? I am passing a `(Any) -> Any` function to a property (in the other case it is an argument), that expects a `(Any) -> Any` function. Logic tells me: Yes, `(Any) -> Any` is of type `Any`, because everything is. But why doesn't that work with the lambda invocation? In fact, I can explicitly cast my lambda to a `(Any) -> Any` function, which will result in an unchecked cast, but it will compile and execution results in a StackOverflowError as expected.

```
{it: (Any) -> Any -> it(it)}.apply { this.invoke(this as (Any) -> Any) }
```

Where is the difference?

Comment: I think you are mistaken in your first assumption.  In the definition: `{it: (Any) -> Any -> it(it)}`, all of the `it`s are the same thing.

Comment: Yes why not? it is a function taking anything as input, which should include another (or the same) function that takes anything as input.

Comment: Ya, you got me.  The completely obfuscational use of `it` totally succeeded in confusing me.  Casting `(Any) -> Any -> Any`, to `(Any) -> Any` is an unchecked cast. Your second example has no unchecked casts.

Comment: FWIW, the signature for `kappa`s mutator is `set(f: (Any) -> Any)`.

Comment: Ok, while I do understand why the use of the mutator is type safe, i still don't get, why the cast of ((Any) -> Any) ->Any is unchecked. In my understanding I should be able to pass a function as a parameter that expects Any, since Any should include a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is, as I said in comments, just a whole lot of irrelevant confusion in the way this question is posed.  Let's start by cleaning some of it up:

```
val fn1 = {x1: (Any) -> Any -> x1(x1)}
```

The type of `fn1` is `((Any) -> Any) -> Any`.  The type of `x1` is `(Any) -> Any`.  The definition above compiles.  The Kotlin compiler has no trouble seeing that `x1` is an `Any`.

The attempt to invoke `fn1` on itself, though, doesn't work.  ... and the compiler says exactly why: `fn1` is a function that is an `((Any) -> Any) -> Any` and cannot be used as an `(Any) -> Any`. Why doesn't that work? Well, because the somebody might invoke the argument!

So that it is easier to discuss, let's create a second function, very similar to the first:

```
val fn2 = {x2: (Any) -> Any -> x2("foo")}
```

It also compiles, just fine.  And now this whole question question boils down to:

**Why doesn't this work: `fn2(fn1)`**

But it should be obvious, at this point.  If that call worked (no matter how much `apply` or `invoke` trickery is involved) the attempt to invoke `x2` (inside `fn2`) can't work, because `x2` is an alias for `fn1`.  It is a call to `fn1` with the argument `"foo"`, where it expects a function.

**tl;dr:  Functions are contravariant in their argument types**

Comment: oh my god, how could I not see that... And not think of contravariance. Thank you, I am seeing it now.